# Is it really helpful to load data from local database creating using pouchDB?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

Is it really helpfull to load data from local database creating using pouchDB ?

please share experience if you used pouchDB. pros n cons.

We have a website which load 1,00,000 records on page load,  and then perform many query on this data,

**What I did :** Create database using their getting-started guide : http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html

Is is possible something like wild card query on this?

Answer (score 1):

For 1,000,000 documents that the user is simply querying, syncing all of them to the client first sounds like it might be overkill.  That's a huge amount of data for your application to wait for at page start.

What you may be interested in trying, though, is storing your data on CouchDB, querying the remote CouchDB, and then selectively syncing documents as needed to the client using filtered replication.  It really depends on how badly you need sync, though, and if the user is ever going to modify those documents and need the changes to be synced back.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's json you can do the queries in javascript. You could start by using localStorage, and move on to using pouchDB if you need more space or need the other functions provided by pouchDB. But if you just want to be able to filter/search records that you've already retrieved on page load, then you can write your filtering logic with javascript.